# How to translate raw HTML code in table data

Tags: angular, html-table

I am getting data from a complex query in a table but the query result also shows raw html code which I need to convert to show it in html format. For better understanding, please check the attached image. In this screenshot,  tags are also coming in table data which I need to translate and display according to that style. For example, I need to show data for 'gen' column in green color.

[image]

Please check the below code I am using

```
            <table class="table stripe" #ConfigurationTable>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let key of debugQueryData">{{key}}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let value of debugQueryValue">{{value}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Please help me out with this. I am working in Angular!

Plus, I have a lot of columns in table. Is there any way to fit all columns in a page without using a horizontal scroller?

Comment: please post the code how can we help without anything

Comment: what is the angular version?

Comment: Code has been posted. Please check now. I am using latest version

Answer (score 0):

Yu havent posted your code but I have some suggestion using Jquery where you can use the function append() to add this query into the  tag. You can use after(), before(), prepend(), append() function which might come in handy for this problem.

- .append() inserts into the tag just after open bracket.
- .prepend() inserts just before closing bracket.
- .after() inserts after the closing tag.
- .before() inserts before opening tag.

Once you do this the file will be rendered as html itself. No need for further changes.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Code has been posted. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have done it using below code

```
<div [innerHTML]="value">
```